# LINQ: use Expression inside Where with anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

Goal: call a method that returns an Expression I can use to chain methods on an anonymous IQueryable.

Example:

```
var allProducts = from p in ctx.Products;
var customWhere = Product.GiveMeYourQuery();
var productsIWant = allProducts.Where(customWhere);
Console.Writeline("yeaaaaah!");
```

This is what I've come up with as to now, which, of course, doesn't work:

```
class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new [] {
                new { Name = "ciao", Age = 18 },
                new { Name = "prova", Age = 28 },
                new { Name = "mah", Age = 38 },
                new { Name = "boh", Age = 48 }
            };

            var myAnon = list.Where(x => x.Name.Length > 2).AsQueryable();
            var thisthat = new MainClass();

            var subset = myAnon.Where(thisthat.Where);
        }

        public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Where<T>(T anon){
            var expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(anon), Expression.Constant(anon)));

            return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>) expr;
        }
    }
```

*Compiler wisdom:* 
../Program.cs(24,24): Error CS0407: A method or delegate 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression LINQInjector.MainClass.Where(anonymous type)' return type does not match delegate `bool System.Func(anonymous type)' return type (CS0407) (LINQInjector)

I feel I'm pretty close, but I cannot really see the path.

Unfortunately I cannot just cast the a' object to a type I create because what the program should output is the SQL (yes, I'm basically building a querybuilder that feeds another tier the queries to execute) and because I'd have to create too many types anyway (each type for each possible chain of joins between tens of tables).

### EDIT:

While I appreciate you trying to show me alternatives and workarounds, at this point I think there's none. This is my question: how to inject Expressions into an anonymous type. If this cannot be done just say so.

Comment: So what do you expect the lambda you've created to do?  As it is it doesn't make sense for a lot of reasons, but without knowing what you *want* it to do, we can't really help you.

Comment: The problem is not what the lambda should do, but how to construct the method that returns it. Anyway: the lambda should take a property from the anon object, compare its value with another value (let's suppose it's hard-coded in the class) and return either true or false accordingly

Comment: But it *is* important what the lambda should do.  It's vitally important in determining even what that methods public API should be, which you don't appear to have gotten right.  How should this method know which property to look at from the anon object?  Where does it get the value to compare it to?

Comment: OK. I have a list of objects called IControls. I set a value in each IControl according to user whishes. Then I cycle through them. Each IControl has a method that returns an Expression I chain to the AsQueryable from LINQ-to-SQL as a Where method. Each IControl knows what properties to look for (I can hard-code the name if really necessary).

Comment: That still doesn't really provide enough detail to answer your question.

Comment: At this point I really don't know what kind of details you're looking for.

Comment: Provide the lambda that you would write if you were hard coding it.  Indicate what aspects of it are known at compile time, and what aspects of it change dynamically.  Currently you're creating a filter given no data whatsoever, and providing no filter at all.  And in the process, you have broken syntax.  Fixing the syntax won't help if you still don't have any actual filtering to perform.  If you don't even know what you want to do, then how can you expect anyone else to help you write it?

Comment: Syntax is my main enemy right now, I don't know what kind of syntax it's expecting. Anyway: at compile time it's known what properties of the anon object I should compare against, what changes at runtime is the value that property value should be compared against. Every compare is simply an equal. At this point I don't care if the expression returns "true" everytime, I'm just curious to see how to use an Expression returned by another method inside a LINQ's Where.

Comment: The syntax you would use would be radically different depending on the type of lambda you want to construct.  Given that you've now actually explained what type of filter you want, and what information is specified dynamically, the solution becomes trivial, and requires no manipulation of expressions whatsoever.

Comment: However I construct my Expression, LINQ's Where is expecting Expression<Func<T, bool>>, I don't seem to be able to provide it.

Comment: You're trying to create a generic method that will only work for a single type.  Don't do that.  If it only works with a single type, use a single type.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to access a property known at compile time of an object outside of the scope in which it's created, you don't want to use an anonymous object.  An anonymous object would be appropriate if you're accessing it using lambdas created in the same scope in which the anon object is created, but you don't want to do that.  You want to have another method statically access a property of that object.  Just give it a name, it'll make everything *super* easy:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public string Name{get;set;} 
    //...
}
```

---

```
public static Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> NameEquals(string name)
{
    return foo => foo.Name == name;
}
```

Comment: Please read the question.
"Unfortunately I cannot just cast the a' object to a type I create because what the program should output is the SQL (yes, I'm basically building a querybuilder that feeds another tier the queries to execute)."

Comment: @Sphaso I did.  Several times.  This solves the problem you described, trivially, and effectively.

Comment: I cannot cast the a' object to another type

Comment: @Sphaso *don't* cast it.  Don't create anonymous types in the first place.  Create instances of `Foo` instead.  As I said before, use anonymous types when you want to access their properties entirely within a single scope.  If you don't want to do that, *don't use anonymous types*; use a named type.

Comment: I need the SQL statement LINQ generates for me, if I use Foo then I don't have any SQL.

Comment: @Sphaso Yes, you do.  From the query provider's perspective there's no real difference between creating an anonymous type and creating a new named type.  By the time the query provider sees the expression the anonymous type actually has a name; it's no longer anonymous.

Comment: are you thinking something along the lines of    
var allProducts = from p in ctx.Products select new Foo { Name = p.name ... };
? Because that doesn't give me any SQL.

Another problem is that what I know is the property name I should look for, but the classes would be different according to the first query (think same column name in different tables).

Comment: @Sphaso Yes, for the third time, *that will work just fine*.  There's nothing special about using anonymous types.  If you want to handle any object with a given property then use interfaces; have the named classes implement an interface exposing the properties you need, and then have the filter method create a filter for objects implementing that interface.

Comment: Sorry but that's not feasible, I'd have tens of classes each with maybe 2\3 properties in common out of a hundred properties for each class, the user can choose joins so I'd have to account for every possible combination. I appreciate your help, but is there any way to do this without using a predefined type?

Comment: @Sphaso Sure, have the method accept a lambda that selects out the property value of the type, although at that point you're not really saving yourself much of any trouble over just comparing that selected value to the constant that you have right there.

Comment: Could you please provide an example as answer?

Comment: @Sphaso I could, but at that point you'd be way better off just not creating this method in the first place, as it isn't really accomplishing much.  You're better off just adding the `Where` directly inline; it'd be about as easy for the caller, and a fair bit of work to write the method.

Comment: I guess I still haven't made myself clear. While each IControl knows what property to look for in the anon obj, I don't know at compile time which IControl (basically which filter) the user will choose. So I cannot just add an inline Where.

Comment: @Sphaso Sure you can.  Just apply the `Where` conditionally, based on whatever check you're using to decide on your custom objects.  `if(whatever)query = query.Where(...);`  Done.  No expression manipulation, no custom types, just a call to `Where`.  Once again, when you explain what you want, getting it becomes easy. When you don't, you become forced to use overly general approaches that don't help.

Comment: I have hundreds of IControl, so the LINQ Where would need to be inside the IControl, which I don't really know how to do using anon type (I hope it's clear by now why I cannot cast)